# Cling labels for beer bottles

Tags: brewing, bottling

Thinking of brewing my own beer and am interested in making some reusable labels using cling stickers - the kind you see for auto window stickers.

Has anyone used cling labels and do they stay adhered when chilled and when the bottle has condensation?

Answer (score 2):

I think they would not make a good candidate for beer or wine bottles if you want to subject them to moisture or cold

[Static Cling Labels](https://www.stickergiant.com/static-cling-decals)

> Static Clings are usually made of a flexible vinyl or plastic that has a very smooth coat and will stick to clean glass surfaces utilizing the moisture in the air and on the glass to adhere to the surface. In cold weather and dry climates static clings tend to dry up, freeze and then fall off easily. The vinyl material will not retain its "cling" abilities for more than a year or two depending on the conditions where the cling is exposed. Some static cling options can be refreshed with soap and water, which is great for long-term use. Static Clings may need a custom quote.<

Answer (score 0):

Cling labels are a great option for reusable beer labels. They are made from a special vinyl material that adheres to glass without adhesive. This means that they can be easily removed and reused, and they won't leave any sticky residue behind.

Cling labels are also very effective at staying adhered to glass, even when the bottle is chilled or has condensation. The static cling properties of the vinyl material create a strong bond with the glass, even in cold or wet conditions.

I have used [custom stickers](https://www.customstickersnow.com/) for my own beer brewing, and I have found them to be very effective. They stay adhered to the bottles even after being chilled in the fridge, and they are easy to remove and reuse.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have no financial relationship with the company you linked to?